# How does the magnet sheet sliding metal mechanism work?

Tags: metals, magnets

I was watching [this video - at 10:23 mark](https://youtu.be/iSid1qz70vw?t=623) where the person was using a hook mechanism for sliding the metal sheets together and noted that sometimes the hook would get caught on a bad angle. To solve this, he used magnets, but I'm not sure how this mechanism works.

If anyone could provide a drawing with explanations where the magnets are placed and how it would affect the sliding mechanism that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that he has just placed some magnets as spacers / sliding surfaces that keep the faces apart.

What has magnets got to do with it? I guess that magnets have the advantage that no adhesive or fastener is required but it's not clear which surface it will stick to.

You could try experimenting with magnetic plastic strip such as found in fridge door seals or fridge magnets. The smooth surface would be low friction.

Comment: It appears that your explanation is reasonably accurate. I think any material which would remain in place as a spacer would provide for the necessary sliding. I suppose the biggest advantage of the magnets is that it keep the stack joined. a substitute material would allow the closed stack to fan out about the joining tabs.